# Unable to use XMeans in Weka 3-7-5 After Installing Via Package Manager

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka, data-mining, xmeans

I am trying to use a clustering algorithm that lets me choose the initial seeds, so I decided to try and use Weka's Xmeans through the weka GUI. However, when I install Xmeans using weka's package manager, it remains greyed out in the GUI, and I am unable to start clustering even after loading in one of weka's provided test.arff files. Can anyone point me into the right direction or suggest another program or java library to accomplish such a task?

Comment: Are all of your attributes numeric? If memory serves me right, Xmeans can only use numeric attributes. I just successfully ran Xmeans on `cpu.arff` which is all numeric, but on `weather.numeric.arff` which contains both numeric and nominal attributes it will not run.

Comment: K-means only works with numerical data. That is probably the reason why it was greyed out. K-means will not allow you to choose the initial means, because it needs to be able to split clusters as desired. I like the implementations in ELKI.